# Updating packages in R - impact of checkBuilt = TRUE or FALSE

Tags: r, installation

I have looked at the help for `update.packages(..., checkBuilt = TRUE)` and I am unclear on why one would not want to have `TRUE` as the default.  The default is `FALSE`.

This question has two parts.  (1) Can someone give a clear explanation of the use of this argument and rationale for either `FALSE` or `TRUE`?

As I understand it, if one updates R, then this could have different outcomes - if the packages haven't been updated, then `FALSE` will not cause the local libraries to be modified with updated packages, while `TRUE` will cause more (all?) packages to be updated. The default option (`FALSE`) may confer a speed benefit - fewer packages will be updated.  Stability is uncertain - a new version of R may work better with a new package, or it may not (e.g. if there are regressions / bugs in the new package), and it may or may not work with the earlier version of the package (backward compatibility is not guaranteed).  Other pros and cons are not obvious to me.  (And I may be quite mistaken here - which is why I ask for a clarification as part 1.)

(2) However, if one has not changed the installed version of R, then shouldn't these have the same outcome?  See [this post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-February/269312.html) for an example where it seems that just calling `update.packages()` created problems, even though the version of R did not change.

Comment: Not an answer, but here's my guess: the `checkBuilt` argument was introduced in r31400 (2004), see also http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/2.1.0/NEWS.rw2010 . At that time, introducing the argument with default `FALSE` meant that the default behaviour did not change which seems most sensible to me. As far as I know, the default value just never changed afterwards. Also, I guess the R core may be reluctant about that as possibly a long announcement similar to announcing functions as deprecated would be needed (and would cause thousands of questions of unsuspecting users...)

Comment: @cbeleites Thanks for responding!  As you're aware - you're the author of the post I linked to, so I hoped you might chime in with more background.  :)  I understand this reluctance to change - that seems like a plausible explanation for the original default and its persistence.  So, in the present, I wonder if users should override the default.

Comment: Sou, you could override the default quite easily. Though I think it isn't worth the effort for `update.packages` (I do it more regularly for things like wrapping `print` around grid based plotting - though also that isn't needed any more with the `Sweave` (`RweaveLatex`) option `print = TRUE`). And then it is much easier to update packages than to downgrade them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`CheckBuilt = TRUE` is especially useful for major upgrades such as 2.14.0 which brought big changes in the namespaces. Packages without a namespace built with previous version of R must be recompiled, otherwise they won't load at all. So if you have such a package (such as [ICE](http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/web/packages/ICE/index.html)) installed in R 2.13, and you update to R 2.14, you won't be able to load it anymore:

```
> library(ICE)
Error in library(ICE) : 
  package ‘ICE’ does not have a NAMESPACE and should be re-installed
```

As there is no newer version with a namespace, update.packages() won't upgrade it without `CheckBuilt = TRUE`. So by saying `update.packages(checkBuilt = TRUE)`, you clearly say, upgrade all the packages if either:

- There is a more recent version on the CRAN
- OR re-install the package if it was built with an older version of R.

It **won't** modify packages that were compiled in the same version of R and without upgrade available on the CRAN. CheckBuilt really means "re-install if compiled in an older version", not "re-install all packages".

Why is it FALSE by default? I guess it puts an huge load on the CRAN and most of the time it is not necessary: I have never seen a problem after a minor upgrade (i.e R 2.13.0 to 2.13.1). I would definitely recommend doing it after any major upgrade such as 2.13.1 to 2.14.0.

I believe the specific case you mention in (2) is an exception. It involves upgrading packages installed with apt rather than from R. You can't really draw any conclusion of such a segfault bug. And anyway, if `CheckBuilt = TRUE` upgraded it, it means it was built in a previous version of R.

Comment: Good point regarding the segfault - that's possibly a red herring.

Comment: I have R 3.2.3 installed and almost all my packages have been installed and compiled using R 3.2.1 or 3.2.2 (according to installed.packages). However if I do update.packages( lib.loc=.libPaths(), checkBuilt=TRUE, ask = FALSE) almost none has been reinstalled.. why?